# Multiple dimension tables with different distributions

Tags: greenplum

I'm working in a distributed database environment (Greenplum) and there are times when I want to access the same (very large) dimension but joining to it on different keys, so I want parallel versions of the dimension with different distribution keys to enable localized joins.

My questions are:

1. Is this a terrible idea?
2. What should I call these alternative distributions?
3. How can I maintain data integrity, i.e. ensure that the data is replicated reliably and efficiently?

My answers so far are:

1. No.
2. I have no good ideas - subdim_xxx? dim_xxx_2, dim_xxx_3? 
   dim_xxx_by_*distkey*?
3. There should be one primary dimension table distributed by the dimension key, and each subsidiary distribution should be updated by looking in the primary dimension for new records and inserting them into the subsidiary - this dimension is not updated so I don't need to worry about that just yet.

Comment: It's certainly not a terrible idea, but whether or not you'll affect the performance enough to justify it is a different question. How big of a dimension table(s) are you using? Typically the distribution key is more crucial on fact tables, due to their size. Redistributing a dimension table on the order of MBs or low 10's of GBs a query time is quite fast on 10Gbe networks...

Comment: The dimension is big. It's transactional data that only has a slightly lower cardinality than the fact tables.

Comment: This sounds like it could introduce quite a bit of additional admin overhead. To make sure that's worthwhile have a look at how big an issue redistribution is for you:
 - What proportion of the query time is spent on motion steps when you look at EXPLAIN ANALYZE?
 - Can the sides of the join be better filtered or pre-aggregated to reduce the number of entries being moved and/or hashed?